# How to use button as a link in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a button in which i want to use as a link as well as want to use ng-click to close the dialog..I mean when i click cancel button the page must be loaded to home page and ng-dialog must be closed.Can anyone help me to solve this problem.The below method does not working .

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location='#/cancel'" ng-click="cancelbtn()">Cancel</a></button>


.when("/cancel",
                {
            templateUrl:"Htmlfiles/Home.html",
                });
```

Comment: Try performing the navigation at end of cancelbtn() funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a scope function which is being called on button click event.

```
$scope.cancelbtn = function()
{
   dialog.close(id)
   $window.location.href= "#cancel";
}
```

Inside you scope function your can change ng-view with below code.

```
$window.location.href= "#cancel";
```

Don't forget to add $window dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is that onclick and ng-click bind to the same event.

I'd recommend that you remove onclick in code and handle that in your controller, inside `cancelbtn()` function. How to do a redirect take a look at `$location` service [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).
You can also send url as a parameter, e.g. `ng-click="cancelBtn('#/cancel')`"